# Create an email and attachment if file exists else create email with different content

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create an email with a predetermined body, header, CC, BCC and subject and to add an attachment.
If the specified attachment is not in the specified folder then create a different email with different predetermined information, in this case the email body would say "there isn't a report today".

The error I get is that the attachment does not exist in the folder.

```vb
Sub DailyReports()
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
    
        strLocation = "C:\Users\Corey G\Dropbox\Vetsure Access Database\Spreadsheets\VSR\PHP Scott Veterinary Clinic" & Format(Now(), " YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
        .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
        On Error Resume Next
        .Display
    End With
    
    If Dir(strLocation) = "" Then
        With outmail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "No Report Today"
            .Body = ""
        End With
    End If

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You most likely need a backslash after Clinic as the filename is currently concatenating with the path if this is representative of your actual code. Useful to use `Debug.Print(strLocation)` to check everything is what it should be when running into these types of error.

Comment: Side note, but you don't want parentheses in `.Attachments.Add (strLocation)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the file is present, *before* attempting to attach the file:

```
Sub DailyReports()
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    strLocation = "C:\Users\Corey G\Dropbox\Vetsure Access Database\Spreadsheets\VSR\PHP Scott Veterinary Clinic" & Format(Now(), " YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
    
    If Dir(strLocation) = "" Then
    
        With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "No Report Today"
            .Body = ""
        End With
        
    Else
    
        With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = ""
            .Attachments.Add strLocation ' per BigBen's note
            .Display
        End With
    
    End If

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```